# How to block a function On Click on a div and how to reactivate on click on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to block the function working just for the class "position", not "position2" nor "position3" of the scroll function when div#onblock -red square- is clicked and to reactivate it when div#reactivate -blue square- is clicked

```js
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > 0 && scroll < 1000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color': 'red))',
      'background': 'rgba(0,40,90,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color': 'rgba(255,248,0,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color': 'rgba(255,0,215,1.00)',
    })
  }
  if (scroll > 1000 && scroll < 2000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color': 'green',
      'background': 'rgba(255,0,144,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color': 'rgba(0,100,206,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color': 'rgba(0,255,7,1.00)',
    })
  }
  if (scroll > 2000 && scroll < 3000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color': 'yellow',
      'background': 'rgba(255,0,226,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color': 'rgba(155,0,255,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color': 'rgba(224,224,224,1.00)',
    })
  }

  if (scroll > 3000 && scroll < 4000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color': 'orange',
      'background': 'rgba(255,2,6,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color': 'rgba(69,66,179,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color': 'rgba(124,141,245,1.0)',
    })
  }
  if (scroll > 4000 && scroll < 5000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color': 'rgba(0,94,255,1.00)',
      'background': 'rgba(255,0,226,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color': 'rgba(224,224,224,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color': 'rgba(155,0,255,1.00)',
    })
  }
  if (scroll > 5000 && scroll < 6000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color': 'cyan',
      'background': 'rgba(255,238,0,1.00)',
      'text-shadow': 'none'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color': 'rgba(176,50,0,1.0)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color': 'rgba(100,16,5,1.00)',
    })
  }
  if (scroll > 5000 && scroll < 6000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color': 'blue',
      'background': 'rgba(243,255,217,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color': 'rgba(136,168,191,1.0)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color': 'rgba(68,47,168,1.0)',
    })
  }
  var color = $('.position').css('color');
  $('#p1color').html(color);
  var color = $('.position2').css('color');
  $('#p2color').html(color);
  var color = $('.position3').css('color');
  $('#p3color').html(color);

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 5000px;
}
#onblock {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
#reactivate {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
}
.position {
  position: fixed;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="position">
  A
</div>
<div id="onblock">
</div>
<div id="reactivate">
</div>
```

Comment: --I need to block the function--- Which function?

Comment: The one that switches the css color property of the class "positon" but not affect to "position2" or "position3" @Seano666

Comment: Sounds like you need an IF statement around that block of code then.  Right?

Comment: Let me see it ! @Seano666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the specific problem of OP. Here is how to do it. For more explanation see the other **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36657538/2825245)**.

```js
var block = false;

$('#onblock').on('click', function() {
  block = true;
})

$('#reactivate').on('click', function() {
  block = false;
})

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  if(block) return;
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > 0 && scroll < 1000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color': 'red))',
      'background': 'rgba(0,40,90,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color': 'rgba(255,248,0,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color': 'rgba(255,0,215,1.00)',
    })
  }
  if (scroll > 1000 && scroll < 2000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color': 'green',
      'background': 'rgba(255,0,144,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color': 'rgba(0,100,206,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color': 'rgba(0,255,7,1.00)',
    })
  }
  if (scroll > 2000 && scroll < 3000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color': 'yellow',
      'background': 'rgba(255,0,226,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color': 'rgba(155,0,255,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color': 'rgba(224,224,224,1.00)',
    })
  }

  if (scroll > 3000 && scroll < 4000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color': 'orange',
      'background': 'rgba(255,2,6,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color': 'rgba(69,66,179,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color': 'rgba(124,141,245,1.0)',
    })
  }
  if (scroll > 4000 && scroll < 5000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color': 'rgba(0,94,255,1.00)',
      'background': 'rgba(255,0,226,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color': 'rgba(224,224,224,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color': 'rgba(155,0,255,1.00)',
    })
  }
  if (scroll > 5000 && scroll < 6000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color': 'cyan',
      'background': 'rgba(255,238,0,1.00)',
      'text-shadow': 'none'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color': 'rgba(176,50,0,1.0)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color': 'rgba(100,16,5,1.00)',
    })
  }
  if (scroll > 5000 && scroll < 6000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color': 'blue',
      'background': 'rgba(243,255,217,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color': 'rgba(136,168,191,1.0)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color': 'rgba(68,47,168,1.0)',
    })
  }
  var color = $('.position').css('color');
  $('#p1color').html(color);
  var color = $('.position2').css('color');
  $('#p2color').html(color);
  var color = $('.position3').css('color');
  $('#p3color').html(color);

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 5000px;
}
#onblock {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
#reactivate {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
}
.position {
  position: fixed;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="position">
    A
  </div>
  <div id="onblock">
    Block it!
  </div>
  <div id="reactivate">
    Reactivate!
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though I see no context between your question and your code. I will try to give you an example of how to stop a function from doing what it does by editing the function itself or by not running the function itself on condition.

Logic is explained with comments...

```js
var enable = true;
var enable2 = true;

$('#enable').on('click', function() {
  if (!enable) {
    enable = true;
    animateIt(); // call again after enabled...
  }
})


$('#disable').on('click', function() {
  enable = false;
})


// in this case you have access to the function...
function animateIt() {
  if (!enable) return; // return from the function if not enabled...
  $('#animateThis').css('margin-left', '0px');
  $('#animateThis').animate({
    'marginLeft': '70%'
  }, 2000, animateIt);
}
animateIt(); // call the function for the first time...









// now let's say you dont have access to this function... or don't want to edit it...

var backup = animateIt2; // create a backup of the function...


$('#disable2').on('click', function() { // on click 'disable' change the function itself...
    animateIt2 = function() {
      return false;
    }
})

$('#enable2').on('click', function() {
  // on enable change the function back to it's old defination...
  if (backup) {
    animateIt2 = backup; //
    animateIt2()
  } else {
    animateIt2()
  }
})

function animateIt2() {
  $('#animateThis2').css('margin-left', '0px');
  $('#animateThis2').animate({
    'marginLeft': '70%'
  }, 2000, animateIt2);
}
animateIt2();
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: Blue;
  color: #FFF;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.clearIt {
  clear: both;
}
#animateThis,
#animateThis2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px 0px;
  background: Red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="enable" class="btn">Enable</div>

<div id="disable" class="btn">Disable</div>

<div class="clearIt"></div>
<div id="animateThis"></div>



<div class="clearIt"></div>
<div id="enable2" class="btn">Enable</div>

<div id="disable2" class="btn">Disable</div>

<div class="clearIt"></div>
<div id="animateThis2"></div>
```

Comment: I guess in my case "enable" is "reactivate" and "disable" is "onblock" and my action is to set a fixed color in my div class and stop the color change at scroll

Comment: You can use the same method for your cases also.

Comment: Added another answer. Check.